# Seperate Headline and Content-Elements with TS and Fluid | Typo3

Tags: fluid-layout, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

i use for a project the fluid template engine. Here i want to seperate all Headline-Elements from the Backend (column normal).

My Idea is, to write in my TS the following code:

```
lib.pageHeadline = USER
lib.pageHeadline{
   [...]
}
```

And in the page object the following code

```
10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
10{
  [...]
  variables{
    [...]
    pageHeadline < lib.pageHeadline
  }
}
```

The problem is to become only the headline. I hope my problem is understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... it's easy.
Here my solution, to render Headlines seperate from the content for Fluid-Templates.

```
temp.pageHeadline = CONTENT
temp.pageHeadline{
    table = tt_content
    select{
        pidInList = this
        where = colPos = 0
    }
    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.field = header
}




pageHeadline < temp.pageHeadline
```

This is all.